# Create dashboards with links in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5, kibana-6

I have created one dashboard based on query, but now I need to add link to it.

Consider below scenario :

[image]

In above image, you can see API name(underlined in red) are needs to be a hyperlinked, so that if user clicked on it, it should redirect to Discover page & run query as APINAME = "ping1"(the one which we clicked)

I don't know whether it is possible or not, atleast I didn't found any such document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [forum link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/create-hyperlink-in-kibana-6-2/134208) that will help to create an hyperlink on kibana dashboard.